# Use macbook keyboard on pc with java

Tags: java, sockets, io

I have a Windows PC connected to my TV, but i can't use its keyboard for some reasons, so i decided to use my macbook keyboard + some Java. 
I've implemented a little socket application that sends my keyboard input to pc on serversocket, but how to use its output on the PC side in Windows apps (Visual Studio, Notepad, Browsers, etc.)?

Comment: There's a program to share your mouse and keyboard from one computer with other computers: [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/). Sounds like it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what i was looking for. But now i'm also interested in the solution to this problem =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class [`java.awt.Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) can be used to generate mouse and keyboard events.